# Capture image foreground - solid background color - preprocessing for CNN

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, image-processing

**PROBLEM**: I have a data set of very similar (grayscale) images, and I want to train a CNN for binary classification. The region of interest is very small, however the position varies a lot. To get an idea, here is one of the images.

[image]

As you can see there is a "tubing" system, which is the region of interest (the central one; not the ones close to the edges of the image). Everything outside the tube is useless. Thus, feeding a CNN with all of this extra information is time consuming and also becomes very hard to gain high performance, since there is enormous amount of noise and other useless information.

**IDEA**: The idea is to paint everything else (except the tube) with a solid color (e.g. black). However, I am really noob with image processing (especially in practice) and I have no idea how to do this automatically. As you can see, the background outside the tube, is pretty similar with the inside of the tube, so I can't really apply a threshold to shade of everything else.

I used OpenCV to apply some edge detection, which could give me some sort of a mask. In order not to repeat the process for every image, I could get this mask from the mean or std image of the data set. Then I could use the mask to paint everything else. Not sure if this going to work, and most importantly I'm not sure how to even start doing it.

What I was able to do towards the edge detection with OpenCV is the following:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.show()
```

[image: edges]

But then I don't know how to fill the tubes with color, and how to apply the mask afterwards. Can you help me?

Comment: Is the area of interest fixed in all images? If so, just crop that part to feed into CNN.

Comment: @horaceT Yes, it is fixed and I have cropped them before. However, there is still a lot of extra information and the CNN I trained didn't seem to learn anything. As you can see I can't crop it too much on the sides because the tubes are prolonged (entrance and exit).